# Generating git.properties file with git information

Tags: git, maven

I am trying to generate `git.properties` file in my project. I have added the [`git-commit-plugin`](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin) dependency in `pom.xml`. Please find my code below

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <dateFormat>MM-dd-yyyy '@' HH:mm:ss Z</dateFormat>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>               <generateGitPropertiesFilename>src/main/resources/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                    <failOnNoGitDirectory>true</failOnNoGitDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Also added git.properties in gitignore file. But i cant generate the properties in my project.

Comment: What Maven command generates the git.properties file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. The above pom.xml has Plugins for git.properties in . In the same pom.xml I missed to add the included

```
    <includes>
    <include>**/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
```

Also in  add the following(besides to PluginManagement)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

Hope this solves your problem to generate git.properties file

Answer (score 3):

here is working example: git.properties will generated under output/classes

```html
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
                    <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>revision</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <prefix>git</prefix>
                        <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                        <injectAllReactorProjects>true</injectAllReactorProjects>
                        <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                        <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <echo>Git-Infos: ${git.commit.id}</echo>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```